# Get total run-time of all video files in subfolders?

Tags: windows-7, video

I have a bunch of AVI files in many folders on an external hard drive. I need to find out the total run-time of all the videos combined.

I know I could toss them into a third party application and get the playlist time, but is there a way to do this without using third party software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open Windows Media Player,
2. go to the Video Tab on your left
3. right click on the video tab and click on Manage Video Libraries
4. click on Add, and add your specific Folder and click on include FOlder
   now, The Media Player tries to upload every video in the subfolder to the player
5. when the uploading process finishes, press the Alt+A to select all the videos
6. now right click on the files and click add to > playlist

It will now show you the duration of all of the videos of all subfolders just like it was answered above

Comment: This is so helpful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten about the grandaddy of media apps: **Windows Media Player**.

I added all the folders to Windows Media Player and plopped them in a playlist. Voila, runtime total. And a bonus, it's native to Windows.

[image]